# ¿Existe un equivalente de using namespace de C++ para Java?

Tags: java, namespace

Bueno, mi pregunta es muy simple. En C++ yo hago esto:

```
using namespace std;
```

Entonces puedo usar los strings. Lo que quisiera saber es, si existe algo en *Java* para importar todas las funciones de una clase.

Ahora, lo que hago es llamar a las funciones de la clase como si fueran propiedades, de esta manera:

```
Sistema.pedirTeclado()
```

Pero quisiera usar la función sin escribir `Sistema`, así.

```
pedirTeclado()
```

### Edito:

Cuando hago una carpeta, y pongo la función dentro de esa carpeta, entonces me funciona, pero cuando pongo todas las funciones en una clase, no me funciona.

¿Hay alguna manera de importar todas las funciones de un solo archivo `.java`?

Mi archivo `Sistema.java` es este.

```
package programa;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sistema
{
    public static int pedirTeclado(Scanner teclado)
    {
        int número = teclado.nextInt();
        return número;
    }
    public static int pedirTecladoDiferente(Scanner teclado,int número)
    {
        boolean permanece;
        while(permanece)
        {
            int númeroTeclado = teclado.nextInt();
            if(número!=númeroTeclado){permanece = false;}
        }
        return número;
    }
}
```

Intenté crear las funciones afuera del `class Sistema`, pero no me deja tampoco.

Comment: Espera, cuando haces `using namespace std` no estas importando todas las funciones de `std`, importas todas las **clases**, por favor edita la pregunta y explica mejor que intentas hacer.

Comment: @rnd Edité la pregunta, no sé si sirva de algo.

Comment: Recien veo la edicion, estaba viendo Copa Davis :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer un [`import static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) de la clase.

Eso hace que todos los *miembros estáticos* (métodos y atributos) de la clase importada se puedan usar como si fueran miembros estáticos estáticos de la clase que los importa.

Por ejemplo, de la clase `java.util.Math`, puedes importar el valor del atributo PI:

```
import static java.util.Math.PI;
```

y luego usar

```
double longitud = 2* PI * radio;
```

Si quieres importar todos los miembros estáticos de una clase, simplemente haz import de `*`.

```
import static java.util.Math.*;
```

Por último, una advertencia: aunque legal y correcta, esta forma de trabajar no se usa mucho<sup>1</sup> y puede hacer complicado leer el código; otra gente puede leer el código y pensar que `PI` está definido en una superclase o en la misma clase, etc. Personalmente, `Math.PI` nunca me ha parecido tan largo como para justificar el tener que usar imports estáticos, y encuentro que Math.abs() ayuda a leer el código mucho mejor.

---

<sup>1</sup>El único caso que conozco en que se aplica habitualmente es para importar los `asserts` de JUnit.

Comment: También los matchers de `org.hamcrest.Matchers`, en librerías de mock como Mockito o PowerMock. Fuera de eso, un ejemplo que recuerdo es con Unirest.

Answer (score 2):

### `import static com.paquete.Sistema.*;`

Esto importa todos los métodos estáticos, osea aquellos declarados con el modificador `static`. Luego pueden utilizarse como funciones, tal y como quieres hacerlo, sin necesitad de *mencionar* la clase:

```
pedirTeclado(argumentos);
```

Si quieres importar un solo método, puedes hacer.

```
import static com.paquete.Clase.pedirTeclado;
```

Este es el mecanismo que utilizan muchos Framworks de testing para las funciones como `assertEquals`.

```
public class Sistema {

  public static void pedirTeclado() {

  }

  public static void pedirVideo() {

  }

  public static int getHora() {

  }
}
```

Comment: No  me funciona, tendría que editar la pregunta. Ahora entiendo que esa `Clase` tiene que ser una carpeta, y crear un archivo por cada función que hago. ¿Hay alguna manera de que `Clase` sea un solo archivo `.java`?

Comment: Lo de las carpetas no puedes hacerlo, en java no puedes hacer metodos a nivel de paquete y las clases no pueden invocarse como funciones.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer, (que es lo que hacen los framworks de testing, por ejemplo) es una clase con todas las funciones que necesitas y que todos esos metodos sean `static`. Ten en cuenta que esto no tiene sentido para funciones de una clase.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo si creas el método que quieres abreviar para que haga la sentencia completa. En tu ejemplo:

```
private void pedirTeclado(){
    Sistema.pedirTeclado()
}
```

Si haces que lo que devuelvan, en su caso, sea lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar static para ya no invocar a la clase. Es util cuando se necesita hacer algo parecido a una libreria por ejemplo la clase math es una libreria que lo puedes importar asi import java.math si no me equivoco, entonces para acceder a sus funciones matematicas solamente invocas para usarlos por ejemplo sqrt() y ya no lo usas asi math.sqrt() aunque de las dos formas se puede, ahora dando un ejemplo mas util puedes crear una clase normal y declara una funcion asi public static sumar(a,b) y desde otra clase la importas e invocas directamente asi sumar(5,6). Nota no pude dar un mejor ejemplo por que estoy desde mi celular luego lo edito.